# Disabling Column Resizing in NSTableView

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstableview

I have been fiddling around with settings for a while, and cannot seem to figure out how to remove that tick. I am assuming now since I couldn't find it graphically, it's code.

I don't want to just drag it out of sight. I'm sure there's code the remove that little adjuster altogether.

[image: Table Slider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the solution you are looking for, but when I get tired of looking at those columns  with their 100px default width, I take the width of the table view and set the width of the column to the same. Then also set the table view to resize columns automatically and last column fills the width.

Comment: These are both good solutions. Either don't draw the headers at all, or make your only column wider.

Answer (score 1):

Why not hide the header bar in the table view?
Just un-tick the 'Headers' check box.

You don't seem to be using the column headers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the column width at least a wide as the table.  The tick is showing the current width of the column.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone came like me searching for disabling column resizing instead of hide the resize handler.

```
extension NSTableColumn {

    func setFixedWidth(_ width: CGFloat) {
        minWidth = width
        maxWidth = width
    }

}
```